# Not enough free space on external mounted NTFS disk on raspberry pi

Tags: raspberry-pi2, ntfs-3g

I have enough free space on my extenral mounted hard drive on my PI.

[image: DF Command output]

I am trying to copy 10GB of files and i get not enough free space message.

If i copy the file one by one i have no problem.

My Sd card has 5GB of free space. I read somewhere that you must have the necessary space on your SD even if you copy to external drive.

Could this be true?

Additional Info:

Part of mount command:

```
/dev/sda1 on /media/XONTROS type fuseblk (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,user_id=0,group_id=0,default_permissions,allow_other,blksize=4096,uhelper=udisks)
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was with the automount in PI.

Mount point `/media` IS NOT proper for mounting disks that you use regular.

I edited `/etc/fstab` adding the disk there and mounting in under `/mnt` and now it works fine.